# A problem on sequence and series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose we have a decreasing sequence $\{x_n\}$ which converges to $0$.

Then is it true that the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{x_n}$$ diverges ?

Comment: Yes it is true. Now, what did you try to show this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a potentially useful trick. Since the $x_n$ are decreasing, you can take a chunk like:

$$\frac{x_{n+1} - x_n}{x_{n+1}} + \frac{x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}}{x_{n+2}} + \cdots + \frac{x_{m+n} - x_{m+n-1}}{x_{m+n}}$$

and bound each of the denominators by $x_n$, so

\begin{align*}&\frac{x_{n+1} - x_n}{x_{n+1}} + \frac{x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}}{x_{n+2}} + \cdots + \frac{x_{m+n} - x_{m+n-1}}{x_{m+n}} \\ \leq &\frac{x_{n+1} - x_n}{x_n} + \frac{x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}}{x_n} + \cdots + \frac{x_{m+n} - x_{m+n-1}}{x_n}\end{align*}

Note something nice happens in the numerators.

Comment: This would let you bound the series above, and in this case by something which isn't necessarily $-\infty$, so it is inconclusive.

Comment: It lets you bound chunks of the series above by $\frac{-1}{2}$. As many chunks as you want.

Comment: Ah, I see, rather than sending $m\rightarrow\infty$ you only take $m$ sufficiently far out to get the relevant chunk.  Rinse and repeat.  Nice.